# Using waypoints.js in Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey Im trying to use [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) in my angular application.. I cant seem to get it to work

**angular-cli.js**

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/waypoints/lib/noframework.waypoints.min.js"
  ]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var Waypoint: any;

export class OurTechnologyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

    //waypoints
    const grinner = new Waypoint({
      element: document.querySelector('.tech-section'),
      handler: function () {
        alert('hello');
      }
    });

  }
```

I am getting an error.. [image]

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

**edit**

Ive installed Waypoints Types and have imported it `import * as Waypoint from 'waypoints';`

getting error `[ts] file pathtofolder/@types/waypoints/index.d.ts is not a module`

Comment: Could you able to solved the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

In app.component.ts replace

```
declare var Waypoint: any;
```

with

```
declare const Waypoint: any;
```

will do the trick.

P.S: I am using Angular 7 at the moment and this solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Waypoints types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/waypoints) for installing type for waypoint.

```
import * as Waypoint from 'waypoints'.
```

I hope it might helps.

Comment: Im getting this error `[ts] file pathtofolder/@types/waypoints/index.d.ts is not a module`

Comment: @A61NN5 waypoints interface library needs an updation. For now you can declare the export for each class inside index.d.ts. Use export package_name = package_name. this should work.

Comment: This is follow up question, tried to implement your solution but didn't. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854977/angular-waypoints-typescript-error-module-not-found