# angular waypoints typescript error module not found

Tags: angular, typescript, types, npm-install, waypoint

I installed the waypoints library with npm install waypoints and added types with

`npm install --save @types/waypoints`.

I get the error /node_modules/@types/waypoints/index.d.ts' is not a module.

[Using waypoints.js in Angular 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144784/using-waypoints-js-in-angular-4-application)

discuses the same problem. The user had the same error. 
One comment suggests "Use export package_name = package_name. this should work" I didn't know how to implement that.

I tried to add

```
export = waypoints
export as namespace waypoints;
declare namespace waypoints { 

}

import * as Waypoint from 'waypoints';
```

When I then try to import the waypoint I get no error.
But if I then add a waypoint like this:

```
let waypoint = new Waypoint.Waypoint({
  element: document.querySelector("#p5"),
  handler: function () {

  },
});
```

I get another error ->

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'waypoints'

Comment: Probably the `Waypoint` import path is wrong. You should import the `Waypoint` module, not the type definition. Don't trust the auto-import too much

Comment: Could you able to solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The exports

```
export = waypoints
export as namespace waypoints;
declare namespace waypoints { 

}
```

will not solve the problem. Don't change anything in @types/waypoints, just add `declare const Waypoint: any;` to the component where you need it. Like simple example

```
declare const Waypoint: any; // Declare the Waypoint class here to access it

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: '<div id="abc">Abc</div>',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    let wp = new Waypoint({
      element: document.getElementById("abc"),
      handler: (direction) => {
        if (direction == 'down') {
          wp.element.classList.add("fadeInUp");
          wp.destroy();
        }
      },
      offset: '95%'
    });
  }
}
```

This is solve the complation error(s). As we know that `Waypoint` will be present once the app is running so just declaring  `Waypoint` class as of type `any` would do the trick.